# Android - determine display size

Tags: android, android-studio

Need to determine which item was selected by user (Small, Default, Large, etc.):

[image]

Is it possible to do this programmatically?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Nothing illegal :) Just trying to calculate the magnification factor for the splash screen.

Comment: It is just changing the density of the display, so your splash screen should already be taking that into account if you want it to look decent on devices, even without Display Size.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine screen display size by using below code

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
    //large
}
else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
    //normal
}
else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
    //small
}
else {
   //other
}
```

Comment: Display Size affects the screen density, not the screen layout size (except indirectly). A large screen size could just as easily mean a 7" tablet or a small display size.

Comment: @ianhanniballake so do you mean that we should check "screen density" instead?